# Perl 5.36.0 synopsis example doesn't work for feature 'class'

Tags: perl

I'm taking an example from Perl's documentation:

https://perldoc.perl.org/blead/perlclass

and trying to execute the following script:

```
use v5.36;
use feature 'class';

class My::Example 1.234 {
    field $x;

    ADJUST {
        $x = "Hello, world";
    }

    method print_message {
        say $x;
    }
}

My::Example->new->print_message;
```

but I get this error:

```
Feature "class" is not supported by Perl 5.36.0 at /home/con/Scripts/class.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/con/Scripts/class.pl line 4.
Command exited with non-zero status 255
```

I'm copying the script *exactly* from the manual, yet the script doesn't work.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @toolic so should I delete this post?

Comment: No, there might be more people confused in the same way. This can help them understand.

Comment: if someone can write that this is a blead version, I'll accept the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your link:

> You are viewing the version of this documentation from Perl blead.
> This is a development version of Perl.

If your code does not run, then you are likely using a different version of Perl.  Perhaps you have the standard version of 5.36.1, which is currently the version documented by this link:

https://perldoc.perl.org

Answer (score 5):

Despite the `use v5.36;` in that example, the `class` keyword was not introduced until Perl v5.37.9. That is an unstable Perl version though.

It is expected (and by "expected", I mean "almost a foregone conclusion") that Perl v5.38 will be the first stable version of Perl to include support for the `class` keyword. That will likely be released in the next few weeks. The `class` keyword will be experimental though, so if you want to use it without warnings, you'll need to include this at the top of your file:

```perl
use v5.38;
use experimental 'class';
```

In the mean time, you should investigate [Object::Pad](https://metacpan.org/pod/Object::Pad) which was the prototype implementation of this feature, and will run on older versions of Perl.

There's also a module called [Feature::Compat::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Feature::Compat::Class) which will load either Perl's native `class` support or Object::Pad, depending on which is available.

Comment: this answer is just as good as the one that I accepted.  I would accept both if I could.

It is very strange that `use v5.36` is a reference in future versions that wouldn't actually work in 5.36

Comment: @con Yup! You can create a ticket [here](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues)

Comment: [Fixed](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/pull/21173) and [applied](https://perldoc.perl.org/blead/perlclass)